# In Android 4, how to do "toggle button" like behavior for other widgets?

Tags: android

I am new to Android, coming from a web app dev background. I have a `HorizontalScrollView` with a list of dynamically added `ImageView`s. When an image is clicked, it should be marked as `selected`, the image then should have an UI effect to reflect the state(a green border or a tick on bottom right corner), when it is clicked again, it should be deselected.

In web development, we could use css classes to reflect an item's ui state by checking whether it has a certain class.

How is it usually done in Android?
Thanks

Comment: change property on onClick event?

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked into ListView?  There's no reason to write that kind of functionality all over again.

Comment: how can a listview scroll horizontal?

Comment: Maybe with this custom implementation: http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34 I haven't tested it though.

Comment: this library they extend the horizontal scrollview. they don't extent the listview while creating the custom view.